Split contributions using price sets
We often need to split donations into several financial types. We can create multiple entries when we enter the transaction, but it's difficult when we've accepted an online donation and the supporter adds a note to split the donation between a couple of different ministries (which are represented by different financial accounts). The best suggestion I've found is to create a Split Donation price set with all the possibilities having a "price" of $1. Then we can split the contribution after the online donation was recorded. However, when testing, as soon as I specify the price set and distribute the total to a couple of ministries specified in the price set - Civi seems to hang when I click on save...
The log is showing an error and then [debug] $backTrace = #0 /home/crmfourd/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(443): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE) .
I duplicated this problem on: https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/, and edited the existing contribution: https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/view/contribution?reset=1&action=update&id=40&cid=12&context=contribution
Has anyone run into this or can suggest a better way to split contributions between several funds?  Thanks!

relates to this thread i believe https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/1t64chk96jrhfqh3md5ok5kk4c
